# PHP Curl - Catch custom protocol error

Tags: php, curl

I have coded a little scraper in PHP which does some request on a password protected website. Normally this website is just requested by an app of the service. 
Now if the session expires the website redirects the user to a page with a custom protocol (xyz://) because this tells the app that the session has to be refreshed and when this happens curl raises an error that the protocol is not supported (because it is a custom protocol). I want to somehow catch this error and refresh the session by myself automatically. How do I do this in PHP?

Comment: maybe use [curl_error()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-error.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if its not a protocol that curl supports (as of writing, DICT, FILE, FTP, FTPS, GOPHER, HTTP, HTTPS, IMAP, IMAPS, LDAP, LDAPS, POP3, POP3S, RTMP, RTSP, SCP, SFTP, SMB, SMBS, SMTP, SMTPS, TELNET and TFTP), then it's not a job for curl. either find a client for that protocol, or you'll have to get down to socket_ api, and implement a minimal client yourself. if you can't find a specification for the custom protocol, you'll have to reverse-engineer the protocol enough to make a minimal client yourself. when reverse-engineering custom protocols myself, rEdoX Packet Editor ( https://github.com/divinity76/old_programs_backup/tree/rEdoX_packet_editor ), Cheat Engine ( http://cheatengine.org/ ) , Microsoft Message Analyzer
 (https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44226 ) , and Fiddler Proxy ( http://www.telerik.com/fiddler ), is my usual go-to tools. (this usually happens when i want to cheat in online videogames) - though, it's usually a painful, difficult and slow process.